# Background Notifications on WatchOS 3 (XCode 8b6)

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, watchkit, watchos

I have foreground notifications on watch working with:

```
class WorkoutInterfaceController:   WKInterfaceController,
                                    UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
```

set delegate:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

receive foreground notification:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void)
{
    print("Received Notification .....")
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    let completionSound: UNNotificationPresentationOptions = [.sound, .alert]
    completionHandler(completionSound)
}
```

add a notification:

```
    let content: UNMutableNotificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.title = "TITLE"
    content.subtitle = "sub title"
    content.body = "message body"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: duration, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: restOverIdentifier,
                                        content: content,
                                        trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    {
        (error) in // ...
    }
```

I have tried on both the sim and device with no luck getting a notification when the sim is locked or on home screen or on watch when the screen goes black if you don't move your arm.

All I am looking for is a simple beep I don't even need the notification alert screen.

Please post code if you have something working for this or confirm this function is not working on watch.

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug with watchOS 3 where only the first notification is displayed:

Changing my code temporarily to:

```
    let id: String = WatchNotify.getUUID()

    //        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: focusWarningIdentifier,
    let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: id,
                                        content: content,
                                        trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

with this added function for a UUID:

```
class func getUUID() -> String
{
    let uuidObj = CFUUIDCreate(nil)
    let uuidString = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidObj)!
    return uuidString as String
}
```

Seems to do the trick although the delegate completion handler does not appear to work on the watch yet.